# Wordpress htaccess internal redirect not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to run an internal redirect (not changing URL in browser) from /recommendations/xxxx to /recommendations/ (which is the home of an SPA that will handle the routing), but I can't quite land the syntax (the `[PT]` comes from the [apache pages](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new)). Can anyone help?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /af2015/web/
# RewriteRule ^recommendations/(\w+) /recommendations [QSA,L] # add_rewrite_rule default
# RewriteRule ^recommendations/(\w)$ recommendations/ [PT] # original
RewriteRule ^recommendations/(\w+)$ recommendations/ [PT]   # per Abel's comment 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /af2015/web/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The rest of the rules will still redirect that to `/af2015/web/index.php` internally. (And btw., `# BEGIN WordPress` indicates the begin of the section you should _not_ manipulate, because WP might overwrite it again by itself.)

Comment: The regex looks doubtful at first glance. `\w` only matches a single character. Is this desired?

Comment: Thanks @AbelCheung, but that on its own hasn't solved it

Comment: @CBroe Not too worried about being in the Wordpress block as I'll implement using `add_rewrite_rule` once I know what I need to arrive at. Don't I need still to point to `index.php` at some stage to get `/recommendations` routed correctly anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I don't fully understand where `add_rewrite_rule` starts and `.htaccess` ends, but turned out no special htaccess was needed, but I did need:

```
function recommendations_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('recommendations/(\w+)', 'index.php?pagename=recommendations', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'recommendations_rewrite');
```